# NO "VLAN ID" Option on some NICs

Tags: networking, vlan

I would like to use VLAN tags on my PC's but some of them only have the option to either enable or disable "Priority and VLAN" but not the ID's. What's the point of enabling VLAN on a specific device if you cannot tag it? Any insights?

[image]

Comment: This is a question of driver suport, some drivers just don't support VLANs for certain OS's or at all. Sometimes the problem is with OEM drivers, and you might be able to get things working with a driver from the NICs manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers for the intel Nic don't allow you to set the vlan there. To do so  you need to install and use their ANS(advanced network services) stuff: see:  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005677.html.

The software  treats VLANS as sub interfaces so you can use the port as trunk....but that said I'd recommend you don't do it unless you have a very compelling reason that you can't solve by using  standard access ports and keeping the vlan config on your switches

Comment: And via the [download site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=36773), you will have to use Intel's PowerShell cmdlets for VLAN configuration.